# Installing tensor flow in Beagle Bone Black

Tags: tensorflow, beagleboneblack, object-detection-api

For a project of mine, I am working on **Beagle Bone Black**(BBB), my objective is to **detect fire from real-time video**. I tried installing **tensor flow**. But neither the normal installation nor installing the pre-compiled binary gave positive results. It gives an **error** saying, '**is not a supported wheel on this platform'**. Does **BBB support tensorflow**? If yes, Could you please help me with this issue?
If not, can anyone of you suggest an **object detection API** which is supported by BBB?
Thanks in advance. 
[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q78K.png)

Answer (score 4):

Some people have seen success installing tensorflow in BBB following the guide found on github. You can find it here https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/GUIDE.md. Hope it helps!

Please note that this should be added as a comment but unfortunately cannot do that (yet).